# Joomla 3 template: php check category and show html

Tags: joomla

Joomla 3.2.1

I have a category with 26 subcategories.

In my template I want to add some code that shows 2 modules if the page is from one of the 27 categories.

I tried this code

`<?php if (JRequest::getVar('view')=='categories' && JRequest::getVar('id')==30) { ?>`

```
  <div id="menu_abc">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu_abc" />
  </div><!-- end menu_abc -->
```

`<?php } ?>`

But that's only one category and it didn't work. The modules didn't show in that one category page (a category list page and an article in one of the subcategories).

I want the modules to show automatic only on all article pages, category list pages en category blog pages of this 27 categories.

Does someone know how to do this? It's only a small piece of code so I prefer not to use another template and cameleon or something if that's possible.

Comment: You are putting that code in your template index.php? Can you please show the conditions you have around it?

Comment: Sorry, the php code didn't come with it in de code... I don't know why. I will try again: `<?php if (JRequest::getVar('view')=='categories' && JRequest::getVar('id') > 30 && JRequest::getVar('id') < 56) 
  { ?>
//HTML code that will show only on the categories page with the id=1
 <div id="intro_abc">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="intro_abc" />
  </div><!-- end titel secretaresse handboek -->
    
  <div id="menu_abc">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu_abc" />
  </div><!-- end menu_abc -->
<?php } ?>`

Comment: Is it a category view or a categories view? Also you should be using JInput since JRequest is deprecated.